# Как запустить java + selenium + cucumber на windows-сервере

Tags: java, selenium, cmd, cucumber

Я меня есть windows-сервер, на котором через консоль должны запускаться автотесты (Java, Cucumber, Selenium), которые написаны в IntelliJ IDEA (+maven) на mac os. Сейчас на сервере установлена только сама java и мне нужно теперь перенести туда автотесты. Как это сделать?

1. Нужно ли переносить всю директорию, созданную IDEA? Директория сейчас весит почти 500MB и, скорее всего, уже включает в себя и используемые библиотеки. Или же достаточно перенести на сервер только jar-файл?
2. Каким образом можно будет запускать код автотестов через консоль, чтобы можно было передавать Тег для запуска конкретного теста?
   На рабочем компьютере запускаю так:

```
mvn -f /autotests/abs/pom.xml clean test -Dcucumber.options="/autotests/abs/src/test/resources/features --tags @TEST2"
```

Но ведь на сервере не будет IDEA (а значит и maven) и файла pom.xml (или его всё же нужно туда переносить?)

Comment: Думаю вообще никак!

Comment: Вообще-то мавен можно установить отдельно, для его работы не нужна IDEA.